# SD CARD ENCRYPTED

Tags: external-sd

I had my SD card encrypted on not 4 my brother turn off my administrative user which delete and rest the password. So he reset to what he thought it was. Now I can't get the SD card to give me the data. How do I retrieve my data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that probably deleted the files in the SD card as well. If that is true there is no fix.